# How does the friction affect force, angular acceleration on a rolling body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, torque

When a mass rolls without slipping on an inclined plane, does the frictional force impart an angular acceleration whilst taking linear momentum out of the mass? Does the frictional force reduce the force on the center of mass whilst causing the object to rotate?